# terminated called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'

Tags: installation, riscv, spike

I have installing riscv in Ubuntu, the final instruction for install is "spike bbl vmlinux"

But I received :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  couldn't allocate 2147483648 bytes of target memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it!
: changed a swap size